# Questions on Python regex

Tags: python, regex

The regex looks like this:

```
r"""\s*(,@|[('`,)]|"(?:[\\].|[^\\"])*"|;.*|[^\s('"`,;)]*)(.*)"""
```

My questions:

1. Are `` [('`,)] `` and `` ['`,] `` different? And why should use `` [('`,)] `` instead of `` ['`,] ``?
2. I don't understand this part of the regex: `"(?:[\\].|[^\\"])*"`. It seems to match a string but I don't know why I should use a group or how this part of the regex works.

Answer (score 3):

1. `` [('`,)] `` and `` ['`,] `` are two *different character sets*. The first one includes the `(` and `)` characters in what can be matched. They parentheses don't group anything, they are matched literally:

   ```
   >>> import re
   >>> re.findall(r"[('`,)]", '()')
   ['(', ')']
   >>> re.findall(r"['`,]", '()')
   []
   ```
2. `(?:...)` creates a *non-capturing group*; it lets you group a pattern without producing a group in the output. It just means that one of `\.`, `.`, or anything *not* using `\` or `"` can match.

Comment: but i just try this one `re.match(r"""\s*(,@|[('`,)]|"(?:[\\].|[^\\"])*"|;.*|[^\s('"`,;)]*)(.*)""", '''"\\""''').groups()` and the output is that `('"\\""', '')` and it still can match `\` or `"`, so i still confused with this part `[^\\"]`  thx a lot :)

Comment: I can't follow your comment even if I decipher where you used backticks. I don't know what your goal is at all with your regular expression. Your question was about the meaning of specific regex syntax however, and I explained what those do.